# Java play framework reverse routing issue

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I have a `routes` with the following routes,

```
GET        /                    com.de.controllers.Application.index()
GET        /facebook/auth       com.de.authenticators.FacebookAuthenticator.auth()
GET        /assets/*file        controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

I tried to call these routes from my controller using reverse routing. I did it like following,

```
 public Result auth() {
    String verifier = request().getQueryString("oauth_verifier");
    if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(verifier)) {
        String url = com.de.authenticators.FacebookAuthenticator.auth().absoluteURL(request());
        RequestToken requestToken = FACEBOOK.retrieveRequestToken(url);
        saveSessionTokenPair(requestToken);
        return redirect(FACEBOOK.redirectUrl(requestToken.token));
    } else {
        RequestToken requestToken = getSessionTokenPair().get();
        RequestToken accessToken = FACEBOOK.retrieveAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);
        saveSessionTokenPair(accessToken);
        return null; //redirect(FacebookAuthenticator.homeTimeline());
    }
}
```

But ,

```
String url = com.de.authenticators.FacebookAuthenticator.auth().absoluteURL(request());
```

giving me an compile error when calling `routes`. How may I fix this? What is the correct way for reverse routing?